# jsPDF messed text format

Tags: jquery, html, pdf-generation, jspdf

I'm using jsPDF plugin so the user can print the Terms and conditions page but when I create the pdf this is the result:

[image: Messed pdf spaces and some characters]

There are numbers and "þÿ" characters that shouldn't appear. Also Extra spacing between some letters and the page is cutted so not all the text is visible.

As I've been reading jsPDF only supports ASCII characters but all of them on my HTML file are fine (or I think so). Is there anyway to fix it?

Here I add my js code:

```
    define(['jquery', 'jsPDF_debug'], function($) {

      $( "#get_toc_pdf" ).click(function() {

      var doc = new jsPDF();

      doc.fromHTML($('#render_me').get(0), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170
      });

     doc.save('ToC');

     });
   });
```

Comment: Did you resolve this? I have a similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40807819/how-to-replace-html-entities

Comment: No sorry, still with the same problem :(

Comment: @HectorLandete it ever got fixed?